# Which options should I use when creating textures for better buildings quality Agisoft?

Tags: point-cloud, mesh, agisoft-photoscan, texture

I am new to Agisoft and I created a 3D module. The textures of the buildings don't look that good. I would like to know which options should I use in the Build Texture tab to make it better.

Or maybe I should change something else?

Is it the point cloud, the mesh or the texture that effect the most the quality of the textures?

[image: Example of how the buildings look in my module]

Answer (score 1):

Take more photos!  Be sure to capture images that point to the different sides of your buildings. Capture images from different drone elevations.  Vary the gimbal pitch during the image capture process. Use ground control and tie points to improve your reconstruction. [See these tutorials](https://www.agisoft.com/support/tutorials/beginner-level/).

Comment: Thank you. I will try these tutorials